# Split a string on the Paragraph marker

Tags: vba, split

I have a text string that is delimited by paragraph markers.  I'm trying to do a split using the paragraph markers but keep getting a type mismatch error.  I've tried the following code but no luck.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
vData1 = Split(vData, vbcr)
vData1 = Split(vData, vbCrLf)
vData1 = Split(vData, vbLf)
```

None of these lines have worked.

Comment: Need to see more. Show where `vData` and `vData1` are being declared and assigned values. Is this Word? If so, you should add the `[word]` tag as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you are confusing a *pilcrow* character (e.g. ¶) with line feeds and carriage returns.

- A carriage return is ASCII character 13. It is typically paired with a line feed and  accomplished by tapping the <kbd>Enter↵</kbd> key.
- A line feed is half of a `vbCRLF` and is ASCII character 10. Combining <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> typically accomplishes a line feed.
- The *pilcrow* character (¶) is ASCII character 182. It is used in MS Word to visually illustrate a carriage return or paragraph terminator but has no functional properties other than as a visual indicator.

My suggestion would be to split on a pilcrow.

```
vData1 = Split(vData, Chr(182))
```

Comment: @Jeeped..............Thanks for the information.  I thought that was going to be the answer.  I get a type mismatch error when it hits that line of code.  When I use the immediate window in the VB Editor, it looks like this:

Comment: Sorry..........it has some data and then the next line has data and so on and so forth.  I copied the data into Word and saw the pilcrows.  I didn't see the pilcrows in the immediate window.  Some how this data has a delimiter but I haven't found what it is yet.  I thought putting it into Word was going to be the answer.  The data is being extracted from a section of a page on a particular web site

Comment: @Jeeped..........I had previously tried chr (10) and chr (13) before posting my question above.  When I look at the data, I don't see any specific delimiter, so I'm assuming that is some ASCII character.  Thanks for the help

Comment: fwiw @Shaves -  a `vbCRLF` (e,g `Enter↵`) is `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` not the other way around..

Answer (score 0):

In My case I Had in MS-Word

Some Text1

Some Text2

Some Text3

Using following Code just worked fine to print Some Text3

```
Sub Demo()
Dim StrTxt As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
         With .Find
              .ClearFormatting
              .Replacement.ClearFormatting
              .Format = False
              .Forward = True
              .Wrap = wdFindStop
              .MatchWildcards = True
              .Text = "<[A-Z]*^13*^13*^13"
              .Execute
        End With
StrTxt = Split(.Text, vbCr)(2)
MsgBox (StrTxt)
End With
End Sub
```